# how to insert image in template of odoo email notifications?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have implemented a module that send emails in leave workflow 
and in the xml file there are : filter , template , automated action ,and server action for each email ...

my question is i want to show an image in the header as below code but it did not work ,

```
  <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[


<img  src="/leaves_workflow_notification/static/src/img/header.jpg">
```

there other solutions ?

Comment: complete the img tag <img  src="/leaves_workflow_notification/static/src/img/header.jpg"/>

Comment: Where did you write that code? In the header tag of a form view?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
<field name="body_html">
    <![CDATA[<img  src="/leaves_workflow_notification/static/src/img/header.jpg"/>]]>
</field>
```

No need to add in header tag, you have to add in email template only.

Comment: thanks but this code is what i used but it did not work , i will explain more ....the module = folder which has the xml file is leaves_workflow_notification and im trying to call the image that in the path above .... please help me im new to xml and odoo as well

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
<field name="body_html">
    <![CDATA[<img alt="" src="/leaves_workflow_notification/static/src/img/header.jpg" />]]>
</field>
```

thanks,

Comment: thanks but this code is what i used but it did not work , i will explain more ....the module = folder which has the xml file is leaves_workflow_notification and im trying to call the image that in the path above .... please help me im new to xml and odoo as well

Answer (score 0):

Use An Image as Background Image:

Suppose your module `your_module` and your image name `your_image.png` and your website base_url is written in `ir.config_parameter`.
When receiver get the email, it will load the image from your server.
The size should adjust by yourself.

Otherwise, you should add attachment to your email.